# Is it possible styling blocks and templates based on screen size in based block-theme of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a question related the custom styles for blocks according to screen size.  For example if I want to align left the text in desktop and center the text in mobile with gutenberg editor and block-theme of wordpress, is it possible? or for example the color or can I have a custom design for mobile, tablet and desktop, using a block theme in wordpress? How would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, block-based themes specify their settings (eg [TwentyTwentyThree](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentythree/blob/trunk/theme.json)) per block for all screen sizes and assume that the values set work for a fluid/responsive design.

Before block-based themes, [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) were commonly used in theme design to establish breakpoints for mobile/tablet/desktop. This technique can still be used for individual blocks by [creating a CSS file per block](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/block-theme-setup/#including-css-for-block-styles) and using a media query within, targeting an individual block.

An example of where I've found this is necessary is the `[buttons]` block. By default, the buttons block can be vertically stacked, but this applies to buttons on all screen sizes. Ideally, I wanted the buttons to be 100% width only on mobile, as this makes sense only for smaller screens. So, I created a custom CSS just for a button block.

NB. The `[buttons]` block is the parent block containing one or more `[button]` blocks, so my CSS is `button.css`, not `buttons.css` (plural).

**Default Button Block, vertically stacked, mobile**
[image: Default Button block, Mobile Preview]

My custom CSS media query for the Button block sets the width to 100% for devices with a max-width for 481px:

**[themename]/assets/css/blocks/button.css**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {
    /* Mobile Style for Buttons */
    .wp-block-button , .wp-block-button__link{ /* block name / target */
        width:100%;
    }
}
...
/* Any other styles specific to button */
```

**[themename]/functions.php**

```php
function myfirsttheme_setup() {
    /*
     * Load additional block styles.
     */
    $styled_blocks = ['button'];
    foreach ( $styled_blocks as $block_name ) {
        $args = array(
            'handle' => "myfirsttheme-$block_name",
            'src'    => get_theme_file_uri( "assets/css/blocks/$block_name.css" ),
            $args['path'] = get_theme_file_path( "assets/css/blocks/$block_name.css" ),
        );
        wp_enqueue_block_style( "core/$block_name", $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'myfirsttheme_setup' );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/block-theme-setup/#including-css-for-block-styles

**Result**
[image: Default Button block with Media Query, Mobile Preview]

Its entirely possible to change background colors or text alignment via the method above, however: those changes can be overwritten by classes applied to the blocks in the Editor. I suggest trying to make the design "fluid" enough so it works across the majority of common screen sizes and only change properties, colors or alignment that can't be done/overwritten by the WYSIWYG Editor for Mobile as needed.

As block-based themes become more common, how this issue is approached may change so keep an eye on the Docs and [Roadmap](https://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/).